# New instance of a linked model, pass 'caller' id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

I'm creating a simple inventory app, there is a view that lists 'items'. It has tables with these rows:

```
<tr>
<td><%= item.title %></td>
<td><%= item.desc %></td>
<td><%= item.value %></td>
<td><%= item.room.name %></td>
<td><%= item.user.username %></td>
<td>
  <%= link_to 'View', item %>
  <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_item_path(item) %>
  <%= link_to 'Delete', item, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
  <%= link_to 'Add Comment', !?????! %>
</td>
/tr>
```

I have a linked model for 'comments' set up but don't know how to pass the `'item_id'` to it when creating a new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [URL helpers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html) actually accept the object to make a route for an association. Meaning, assuming you have a nested route for comments within items,

```
resources :items do
  resources :comments
end
```

you can [`link_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) the `new_item_comments_path(item)`.

The method `new_item_comments_path(item)` makes a string URL based on the `new_item_comments` route, which you feed to `link_to` to make an HTML `<a>` tag.

To be clearer, in your view you would have:

```
  <%= link_to 'View', item %>
  <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_item_path(item) %>
  <%= link_to 'Delete', item, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
  <%= link_to 'Add Comment', new_item_comments_path(item) #-> (instead of ???) %>
```

In this case, the `item` you are passing is the reference to your current item, which allows the URL helper to make a URL for it from the route.

The [Rails guide for routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#generating-paths-and-urls-from-code) should be a useful read for you.

Now that's assuming your Comment controller assigns the right stuff at the right place. You seemed to have figured that out, but I'll explain for the sake of clarity (and future visitors)

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  # GET /item/:item_id/comments/new
  def new
    @comment = Comment.new

    @item = Item.find(params[:item_id])
    @comment.item = @item
    # render
  end

  # POST /item/:item_id/comments
  def create
    @comment = Comment.new(params[:comment])

    @item = Item.find(params[:item_id])
    @comment.item = @item

    # if @comment.save blah
  end
end
```

Comment: What goes in the place of: `new_item_comments_path` exactly? I was expecting it to look more like: `..., item, method: :add_comment...` like the delete function? Do I need to add a `add_comment` method to my item controller?

Comment: In fact, the `new_item_comments_path` helper goes directly to your `Comment#new` controller, so there's no need to specify it. I linked to the guide on routing, which should solve a few questions for you.

Comment: `new_item_comments_path(item)` gives `undefined method` but `new_item_comment_path(item)` leads to create a new comment. However when I look at the comment in rails console it shows `item_id: nil`?

Comment: Would I need to add something like: `@comment.item_id = ...` to the create method in the controller?

Comment: I might have messed up the plurals here (I do that often), indeed, it must be `new_item_comment_path` (since you're creating one comment). And indeed, also, your controller would need to set that up. (I'll edit my answer)

Comment: `Couldn't find Item without an ID` is what shows now as an error when running `create`. On the error screen in the browser, in the list of parameters there is no `item_id` is this the problem?

Comment: The `create` action hasn't been fed an Item ID. Verify your [`form_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for) tag in your `new` view.

Comment: I have `_form.html.erb` file that starts: `<%= form_for(@comment)...` there isn't any form_for in the 'new' file. In the _form file there is: an if for comment errors, two fields and one action. No mention of any @item.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20515/discussion-between-jonallard-and-charlie-egan)

Answer (score 0):

All credit should go to @jonallard

The solution is all about routing it seems, you need to pass a url to the form that makes new comments (linked models).

to do this:

1. Add this (or similar depending on object names) to the page that is calling the creation:

   `<%= link_to 'Add Comment', new_item_comment_path(@item) %>`
2. In both the `new` and the `create` method of the `comments_controller` there is a line starting `@comment = Comment.new`. Under that line add:

   `@item = Item.find(params[:item_id])` AND
   `@comment.item = @item`
3. edit the top line of the comments template for to: `<%= form_for(@comment, {:url => item_comments_path(@item)}) do |f| %>`
4. Edit routes to somethings like:

> resources :items do
>
> ...
>
> resources :comments
>
> end

and Read this: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#creating-paths-and-urls-from-objects!

As mentioned before all credit goes to @jonallard, his answer and his expertise.